How to reset state after a hot reload in react?
I am resetting data after a hot reload (when the project is saved locally). The issue arises because I am using window.open, and after a hot reload, window.open is triggered automatically since the data persists in the component state. This happens due to the execution of useEffect on reload. To prevent this, I introduced an isMounted flag and added cleanup. Please review the code below and let me know if there is a better way to handle this.
const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    // LOGIC to update data on button click 

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(data){
            window.open('https://example.com', '_blank')
        }
    }, [data])

As react keeps data in the state after saving the project locally, I changed the isMount value before reloading. below is the change done
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
const isMounted = useRef(false);

// LOGIC to update data on button click 

useEffect(()=>{
    return ()=>{
        //cleanup before unmount 
        isMounted.current = false
    }
}, [])

useEffect(()=>{
    if(isMounted.current){
        if(data){
            window.open('https://example.com', '_blank')
        }
    }else{
        isMounted.current=true
    }
    
}, [data])


You have several errors on the code. First, the use of the useRef(), the correct syntax is:
const isMounted = useRef(false);

then, according to the comments you're trying to run a useEffect() that runs a cleanup function when the component unmounts and you have a value inside the dependency array, making that cleanup function execute on each change of data:
useEffect(()=>{
    return ()=>{
        //cleanup before unmount 
        isMounted.current = false
    }
    /* cleanup will run only on unmount and also data is not used inside this useEffect so is not needed */
}, [])

Try this fixes.
Hope this helps!

Thanks Daniel, sorry I made erros while pasting my code. I corrected my question. Your code is exactly what I did. But I am not sure if it's a react best practise and I am not overcomplicating my problem.

For a boolean value, is always better to use a state as hot reloading will not recreate this value and will store it for when it reloads and even more because Is only for development purposes as on a production build you will not have hot reloading. References are more used on actual components other than plain values because they are used to avoid the react lifecycle.

I tried the same example with useState instead but a new window opens post each hot reload.

ok, perhaps the problem is the unmounting of the component. First, put a console.log inside the cleanup function to see if it's executing. If so, then the problem is that the component is unmounting when hot reloading and then mounting again, making all the states and ref values to be at their initial state. To solve this, maybe you can move the value to a parent component or even better, to a Context with a provider on the App.js making sure it's managed correctly.
